# How to create CSV file instead of .PART file in SELECT INTO OUTFILE S3

Tags: mysql, amazon-s3, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, into-outfile

I'm using SELECT INTO OUTFILE S3 command to move output of queries to an S3 bucket via a Stored Procedure. The front-end application has to read these files and show them on the screen. But, the output files produced by this command is of type .part_0000, which the front-end application is unable to read.
Is there a way to force .csv or .text extension on these files produced by the command or is there a way for a react application to read .part files ?

The command that I'm using -

```
select * from My_table
 INTO OUTFILE S3 's3://my_bcuket/folder/filename'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    FORMAT CSV HEADER
    OVERWRITE ON
```

- The output file = s3://my_bcuket/folder/filename.part_00000
- Version of Aurora RDS= 2.11.2 ;
- MySql = 5.7.12
- Reference document used - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.SaveIntoS3.html

FORMAT, the optional keyword allows for CSV and TEXT but it's more about the data format than about file type and extension I guess ? Adding it or removing it didn't make any difference.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The article by provided link explicitly tells that the extension will be added to the specified prefix. Unconditionally. And does not provide the way to eliminate it. Versioning...